# Problema con RewriteRule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, rewriterule

Hola tengo un problema a en una web local (XAMPP) en el cual al crear el MVC de php tengo las vistas y controladores estructurados por carpetas. La cosa es que en mi raiz tengo un index.php que redirige dentro de la carpeta "pages" a la entrada de la web.

Como consecuencia la url a día de hoy es localhost/pages/red.php y me gustaría mostrar solo localhost/red, luego la siguente es localhost/step-x y quisiera cambiarlo por localhost/datos por ejemplo.

El htacces no me está haciendo caso (cuando pongo un 404 o así si) este es mi codigo:

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewritebase /
RewriteRule ^red(/.*|$) pages/red.php [NC,END]
```

Tengo cambiada la config del apache de XAMPP para que me ponga la web por default quedando así:

```
DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/maqueta"
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/maqueta">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   AllowOverride FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Hola, ¿dónde pusiste el archivo .htacces?, ya que si quieres que funcione con la dirección del localhost/ entonces deberías modificar el .htacces de la raíz de los proyectos, en XAMP sería _xampp/htdocs_

Comment: No se si es ahí donde debería ir, cambie la configuracion del XAMPP para que "localhost" apuntase a mi sitio (por el tema de ajax y scripts me era más comodo). Te actualizo la información

Comment: Por lo que veo, tu archivo debe estar ubicado en "C:/xampp/htdocs/maqueta/.htaccess"